# EF6 Self Referencing Table with multiple parent properties, single child collection

Tags: entity-framework, data-annotations, fluent, self-referencing-table

I have a table that references itself, but I am struggling with getting my desired mapping. I want to be able to define Children to be a collection of people that have a given person as Mother, Father, and/or Guardian.  A Guardian may be the father or mother.

I am wanting to have a tree view of people that is browsable where people are listed; the user can expand a person's node to show all that person's children, regardless off the child-defining relationship (Mother, Father, or Guardian).

```
public partial class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public int? GuardianID { get; set; }

    [Column("MotherID")]
    public int? MotherID { get; set; }


    [Column("FatherID")]
    public int? FatherID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MotherID")]
    public virtual tblPerson Mother { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FatherID")]
    public virtual tblPerson Father { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GuardianID")]
    public virtual tblPerson Guardian { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Guardian")]
    [InverseProperty("Father")]
    [InverseProperty("Mother")]
    public virtual IEnumerable<tblPerson> children { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated right now my view has to look like this:

```
    @using Person_MVC.Models
    @model IEnumerable<Person>
    @{
        IEnumerable<Person> children;
    }

    <ul>
        @foreach (Person person in Model.OrderBy(p => p.PersonNumber))
        {
            <li id="Pnl_@Person.ID" data-jstree='{"type":"Person"}' data-Personkey="@Person.ID.ToString()">
                @Person.Name
                @{
            PersonModel db = new PersonModel();
            children = (from p in db.Persons where p.GuardianID == Person.ID || p.Father == Person.ID || p.MotherID == Person.ID select p).ToList();
                }
                @if (children != null && children.Count() > 0)
                {
                    @Html.Partial("PersonTree", children)
                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the better solution is to make three navigation lists in your model and may have one method to join the objects to return all sons to you.

e.g.

```
public int? FatherId { get; set; }

public int? GrandFatherId { get; set; }

public int? MotherId { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Person> FatherForThose { get; set; }
public virtual Person Father { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Person> GrandFatherForThose { get; set; }
public virtual Person GrandFather { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Person> MotherForThose { get; set; }
public virtual Person Mother { get; set; }


public ICollection<Person> GetChildren()
{
    var list = FatherForThose.Concat(MotherForThose).ToList();
    foreach (var person in GrandFatherForThose)
    {
        if (list.All(i => i.Id != person.Id))
        {
            list.Add(person);

        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

but you should always take care to include them in your querying
e.g.

```
var grand = context.Persons.Include(x => x.FatherForThose)
            .Include(x => x.GrandFatherForThose)
            .Include(x => x.MotherForThose)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 2);

var list = grand.GetChildren();
```

Answer (score 1):

1. All the table data should be in hand (If not we might have multiple calls to database).
2. Find list of all the Persons who doesn't have parents(i.e; no guardianid, motherid, parentid for a person) and start the partial with them.

Answer (score 0):

Try can this too...

```
public partial class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }


        public int? GuardianID { get; set; }

        [Column("MotherID")]
        public int? MotherID { get; set; }


        [Column("FatherID")]
        public int? FatherID { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Person> Children { get
                {
                    return context.Person.Where(p => p.GuardianID == this.ID || p.Father == this.ID  || p.MotherID == this.ID).ToList();
                } 
        }
    }





 @using Person_MVC.Models
    @model IEnumerable<Person>

    <ul>
        @foreach (Person person in Model.OrderBy(p => p.PersonNumber))
        {
            <li id="Pnl_@Person.ID" data-jstree='{"type":"Person"}' data-Personkey="@Person.ID.ToString()">
                @Person.Name

                @if (Person.Children != null && Person.Children.Count() > 0)
                {
                    @Html.Partial("PersonTree", Person.Children)
                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
```